# insert database elements in an array.

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I want to add database elements into array. 
how do I do that.

the table row has elements a to d.

i want to do this because.
I have created a quiz and each time the user answers a question the answer in stored in a database. the questions are multiple choice. so a, b, c or d. (there are 5 questions) i am creating a servlet score page. so once they are in an array the i can check each element.

here is my code

```
private String ans[];
...  
int i = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
ans[i] = {rs.getString(1)};
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using an `ArrayList<String>` instead.

```
private ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();
...

while (rs.next()) {
    ans.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: beat me by like 5 seconds, but depending on the size a LinkedList will be more effecient.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
private String ans[];
...  
int i = 0;

while (rs.next()) {
ans[i] = rs.getString(1);
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private LinkedList<String> ans = new LinkedList<String>();
//...  

while (rs.next()) {
ans.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

This would work better as you can have multiple elements.